# The periodization of the Dirichlet kernel on the real line (Stein & Shakarchi, Chapter 5, Ex #16)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, periodic-functions

Here's problem 16 from Stein & Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis Chapter 5:

The Dirichlet kernel for periodic functions of period $1$ is defined by $$\mathcal{D}_R(x) = \widehat{\chi_{[-R,R]}}(x)=\frac{\sin(2\pi Rx)}{\pi x}.$$

Also, the modified Dirichlet kernel for periodic functions of period $1$ is defined by

$$\mathcal{D}^*_N(x) = \sum\limits_{|n|\leq N-1} e^{2\pi inx}+\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{-2\pi iNx}+e^{2\pi i Nx}\right)$$

Show that the result in Exercise 15 $\left(\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+\alpha)} = \frac{\pi}{\tan\pi\alpha}\right)$gives

$$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \mathcal{D}_N(x+n) = \mathcal{D}^*_N(x),$$

where $N\geq 1$ is an integer, **and the infinite series must be summed symmetrically**. In other words, the periodization of $\mathcal{D}_N$ is the modified Dirichlet kernel $\mathcal{D}^*_N$.

***I couldn't figure out what the sentence in bold really meant and if it was needed for the solution.***

I attempted a solution anyways, and it doesn't seem to be necessary:

Noticing that the numerator of the Dirichlet kernel (on the real line) is

$$\sin(2\pi N(x+n))= \sin(2\pi Nx+2\pi Nn) = \sin(2\pi Nx)\cos(2\pi Nn) + \sin(2\pi Nn)\cos(2\pi Nx) =\sin(2\pi Nx)\cdot 1 + 0 = \sin(2\pi Nx)$$ because $n,N \in \mathbb{Z}$, one gets $$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi Nx)}{\pi(x+n)} = \frac{\sin(2\pi Nx)}{\pi}\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x+n)}=_{15} \frac{\sin(2\pi Nx)}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\pi}{\tan\pi x} = \frac{\sin(2\pi Nx)}{\tan\pi x},$$

Now if only one could show that $\frac{\sin(2\pi Nx)}{\tan\pi x} = \mathcal{D}^*_N(x)$.

Using the complex exponential identities for $\sin$ and $\cos$, and that $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$:

$$\frac{\sin(2\pi Nx)}{\tan\pi x} = \frac{e^{2\pi iNx}-e^{-2\pi i Nx}}{\require{cancel}\cancel{2i}}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{e^{\pi ix}-e^{-\pi i x}}{\cancel{2i}}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{e^{\pi ix}+e^{-\pi i x}}{2}}} = \frac{e^{2\pi iNx}-e^{-2\pi i Nx}}{e^{\pi ix}-e^{-\pi i x}}\cdot \frac{e^{\pi ix}+e^{-\pi i x}}{2}$$

$$= \left\{\left[\frac{e^{\pi i x(2N+1)}-e^{-\pi i x(2N+1)}}{e^{\pi i x}-e^{-\pi i x}}\right]+\left[\frac{e^{\pi i x(2N-1)}-e^{-\pi i x(2N-1)}}{e^{\pi i x}-e^{-\pi i x}}\right]\right\}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

letting $\xi  = e^{2\pi i x}$,

$$e^{\pi i x(2N+1)}-\frac{1}{e^{\pi i x(2N+1)}} = \frac{e^{2\pi i x(2N+1)}-1}{e^{\pi i x(2N+1)}} = \frac{\xi^{(2N+1)}-1}{e^{\pi i x(2N+1)}}, e^{\pi i x(2N-1)}-\frac{1}{e^{\pi i x(2N-1)}} = \frac{e^{2\pi i x(2N-1)}-1}{e^{\pi i x(2N-1)}} = \frac{\xi^{(2N-1)}-1}{e^{\pi i x(2N-1)}}, e^{\pi i x}-\frac{1}{e^{\pi i x}} = \frac{e^{2\pi i x}-1}{e^{\pi i x}} = \frac{\xi -1}{e^{\pi i x}} $$

thus

$$\frac{\xi^{(2N+1)}-1}{e^{\pi i x(2N+1)}}\cdot\frac{e^{\pi i x}}{\xi -1} = \frac{\xi^{(2N+1)}-1}{\xi -1}\cdot \frac{1}{\xi^N}, \frac{\xi^{(2N-1)}-1}{e^{\pi i x(2N-1)}}\cdot \frac{e^{\pi i x}}{\xi -1} = \frac{\xi^{(2N-1)}-1}{\xi -1}\cdot \frac{1}{\xi^{N-1}}$$

using the geometric series

$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\frac{\xi^{2N}+\xi^{2N-1}+\cdots+1}{\xi^n}+ \frac{\xi^{2N-2}+\xi^{2N-3}+\cdots+1}{\xi^{N-1}}\cdot\frac{\xi}{\xi}\right\} =\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\frac{\xi^{2N}+2\xi^{2N-1}+2\xi^{2N-2}+\cdots+2\xi+1}{\xi^N}\right\} $$
\\
\\
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left\{\xi^N +\xi^{-N} +2(\xi^{N-1}+\xi^{-(N-1)})+2(\xi^{N-2}+\xi^{-(N-2)})+2(\xi^{N-3}+\xi^{-(N-3)})+\cdots+2(\xi-\xi^{-1})+2\right\} $$
\\
\\
$$= \frac{1}{2}\cdot[\xi^{N}+\xi^{-N}] + \sum\limits_{|n|\leq N-1} \xi^{n} = \mathcal{D}^*_N(\xi)$

where $\xi = e^{2\pi i x}$. That is my attempt at a solution, is it correct? Even without the sentence in bold?

Comment: I believe the series is not summable but you get cancellation if you use $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N$

Comment: @CalvinKhor I’m not sure how I have to make use of the summing symmetrically to solve the problem? The way it’s written it’s like it’s a vital part of solving the problem, and it ‘looks’ like I’ve solved it without. So I was wondering if my solution is correct, better yet, where to make use of summing symmetrically.

Comment: no, not correct, technically, because you never worried about convergence. The sum $\sum_n 1/(x+n)$ does not converge in the usual sense. Compare with harmonic series

Comment: I’m aware of the divergence. Where does it need to be applied specifically?

Comment: Because exercise 15 implies the convergence of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{x+n}$ to $\frac{\pi}{\tan\pi x}$, summed symmetrically, and then we’re multiplying the series by $\frac{\sin(2\pi N x)}{\pi}$

Comment: i don’t understand you. You are aware that you used this symmetric sum result early on in your post? This is where you used that it is summed symmetrically.  If you don’t symmetrically sum you cannot apply Exercise 15. Or have I gravely misunderstood you and your problem…?

Comment: The problem asks to use the result of Exercise 15, the result is presented in brackets above, where you do have to sum symmetrically, but it is nevertheless a whole other problem in itself. The problem then asks to show that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathcal{D}_{N}(x+n) = \mathcal{D}_{N}^* (x)$ for $N \geq 1$, followed by the grave warning: ⚠️ the infinite series must be summed symmetrically ⚠️ implying the latter sum, but it’s just the result of Exercise 15 multiplied by $\frac{\sin(2\pi Nx)}{\pi}$… at least as far as I can see it. So why the warning, and the use of the word ‘must’ ?

Comment: It ‘feels’ like I answered the problem avoiding summing symmetrically, I obviously didn’t avoid it because you need to sum symmetrically to show $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{(x+n)} = \frac{\pi}{\tan\pi x}$ but I had done Exercise 15 before doing this one.

Comment: My guess is that this is emphasis. The result is false without symmetrically summing, because the unordered sum has no meaning ; isn’t that a good enough reason to say ‘must’?

Comment: True, but if you read the question as a stand alone, it looks like you need use symmetrical summing somewhere in the question. The reason why I’m asking is this is an old hw assignment, and I understood it that way, and also when I got it back, the comments were something like, okay the answer looks good, but how did you make explicit use of summing symmetrically? If it’s just emphasis, I’m okay with that, I just want to be sure I didn’t miss anything or didn’t fully understand a concept more importantly in my answer submission, also that my answer is indeed correct

Comment: would you like to move to chat?

Comment: I should be asleep :) but I’ll check tomorrow. I don’t see anywhere else it could be used. Perhaps the instructor just wanted to see that you knew you ‘had license’ to apply exercise 15…

Comment: Ahaha I’m so sorry! I have no way of seeing your time zone! Thanks I appreciate it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133057/discussion-between-calvin-khor-and-no-lemon-no-melon).